# Как последовательно анимировать элементы pattern?

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

```html
 <svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
     <defs>
      <pattern
        id="dotted-pattern"
        viewbox="0,0,100,100"
        height="3.125%"
        width="3.125%">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="#10446D" r="12">
        <animate
         attributeName="opacity"
         values="0; 1"
         keyTimes="0; 1"
         dur="3s"
         begin="0s"
         repeatCount="1"
         fill="freeze" />
       </circle>
      </pattern>
      <mask id="circle-mask" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="38.48" width="100" height="100" fill="white"></circle>
      </mask>
     </defs>
    
     <rect
       width="74"
       height="74"
       y="13"
       x="13"
       mask="url(#circle-mask)"
       fill="url(#dotted-pattern)"></rect>
    </svg>
```

Таким образом, анимация запускается одновременно для всех элементов `pattern`.

Как запустить анимацию следующего элемента последовательно, если анимация предыдущего элемента завершна?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/60408666/7394871

Answer (score 3):

> [Перевод ответа @enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409177/7394871) на вопрос EnSO: [How to animate pattern
>   items sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60408666/7394871)

Вместо того, чтобы анимировать круги внутри шаблона, я бы анимировал радиальный градиент от белого к черному, и  использовал бы этот градиент, чтобы заполнить круг маски следующим образом:

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
     <defs>
        <radialGradient id="rg" cx=".5" cy=".5" r="0.01">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="black"></stop>
          <animate
         attributeName="r"
         values="0.01; 1"
         dur="3s"
         begin="0s"
         repeatCount="1"
         fill="freeze" />
  </radialGradient>
      <pattern
        id="dotted-pattern"
        viewbox="0,0,100,100"
        height="3.125%"
        width="3.125%">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="#10446D" r="12"/>
        
      </pattern>
      <mask id="circle-mask" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <circle id="kk" cx="50" cy="50" r="38.48" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#rg)">
            
          </circle>
      </mask>
     </defs>
    
     <rect
       width="74"
       height="74"
       y="13"
       x="13"
       mask="url(#circle-mask)"
       fill="url(#dotted-pattern)"></rect>
        
        
    </svg>
```

### Второе решение

Вы можете заполнить круг маски белым и анимировать радиус маски следующим образом:

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
     <defs>

      <pattern
        id="dotted-pattern"
        viewbox="0,0,100,100"
        height="3.125%"
        width="3.125%">
       <circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="#10446D" r="12"/>
        
      </pattern>
      <mask id="circle-mask" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
       <circle id="kk" cx="50" cy="50" r="38.48" width="100" height="100" fill="white">
            <animate
         attributeName="r"
         values="0.01; 38.48; 38.48;0.01 "
         dur="6s"
         begin="0s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         fill="freeze" />
          </circle>
      </mask>
     </defs>
    
     <rect
       width="74"
       height="74"
       y="13"
       x="13"
       mask="url(#circle-mask)"
       fill="url(#dotted-pattern)"></rect>
        
        
    </svg>
```

Comment: Саша а можно сделать так что бы паттерн заполнял анимированно ?

Comment: Щас я в чат напишу